# transforming xml by using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

i need help in getting the below output from shops.xml file( where incity="yes" and type="Botique" ) by using xsl . As i am new to xslt , so any help would be highly appreciated.

shops.xml:

```
<shops>     
<shop incity="yes" onlineorder="yes">         
<type>Botique</type>         
<address>  
<streetno>23</streetno>
<streetname>collins</streetname>
<suburb>Melbourne</suburb>
</address>     
</shop> 
<shop incity="yes" onlineorder="yes">         
<type>Botique</type>         
<address>  
<streetno>25</streetno>
<streetname>little collins</streetname>
<suburb>Melbourne</suburb>
</address>     
</shop> 
<shop incity="no" onlineorder="yes">         
<type>Tailoring</type>         
<address>  
<streetno>2</streetno>
<streetname>cosmos street</streetname>
<suburb>Glenroy</suburb>
</address>     
</shop>  
</shops>
```

output:

```
<shops>     
<shop  onlineorder="yes">         
<type>Botique</type>         
<address>  23 collins,Melbourne </address>     
</shop> 
<shop onlineorder="yes">         
<type>Botique</type>         
<address> 25 little collins, Melbourne </address>     
</shop> 
</shops>
```

shop.xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">   
<xsl:template match="shop[@incity='no']" />    
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">     
<xsl:copy>    
<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>     
</xsl:copy>   
</xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

shop.php

```
<?php
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$xmlDoc->formatOutput = true;
$xmlDoc->load("shops.xml");
$xslDoc = new DomDocument;
$xslDoc->load("shop.xsl");
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xslDoc);
$strxml= $proc->transformToXML($xmlDoc);
echo ($strxml);
?>
```

Comment: What code have you written so far? Where did you get stuck? There are some good tutorials out there. E.g. http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/

Comment: @James above is my xsl, but it shows the output without tags and also not showing the attribute onlineorder="yes"

Comment: OK - can you include the XSL you're using too please?

Comment: @James: reformatted the XSL paragraph. I didn't have the indent.

Comment: @James its now showing xsl file

Comment: @James [Good things at w3schools?](http://w3fools.com/)

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, shortest and easiest solution that uses one of the most fundamental XSLT design patterns -- overriding of the identity rule.

Comment: @sara: Have you seen my answer and is it useful to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something to start with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="shops">
    <xsl:element name="shops">
      <xsl:for-each select="shop">
        <xsl:if test="@incity='yes'">
          <xsl:if test="type='Botique'">
            <xsl:element name="shop">
              <xsl:attribute name="onlineorder">
                <xsl:value-of select="@onlineorder"/>
              </xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:element name="type">
                <xsl:value-of select="type"/>
              </xsl:element>
              <xsl:element name="address">
                <xsl:value-of select="address/streetno"/>
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="address/streetname"/>
                <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="address/suburb"/>
              </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<shops>
  <shop onlineorder="yes">
    <type>Botique</type>
    <address>23 collins, Melbourne</address>
  </shop>
  <shop onlineorder="yes">
    <type>Botique</type>
    <address>25 little collins, Melbourne</address>
  </shop>
</shops>
```

Comment: @sara, works fine for me. I ran it with your PHP code in PHP version 5.2.14. What kind of errors are you getting?

Comment: @mizo Warning: DOMDocument::load() [function.DOMDocument-load]: attributes construct error in shopping/shop.xsl, line: 2 in shopping/shop.php on line 6

Warning: DOMDocument::load() [function.DOMDocument-load]: Namespace prefix xsl on stylesheet is not defined in shopping/shop.xsl, line: 2 in shopping/shop.php on line 6

Comment: @mizo Warning: DOMDocument::load() [function.DOMDocument-load]: Couldn't find end of Start Tag stylesheet line 2 in shopping/shop.xsl, line: 2 in shopping/shop.php on line 6

Warning: DOMDocument::load() [function.DOMDocument-load]: Extra content at the end of the document in shopping/shop.xsl, line: 2 in shopping/shop.php on line 6

Warning: XSLTProcessor::importStylesheet() [function.XSLTProcessor-importStylesheet]: compilation error in shopping/shop.php on line 8

Comment: @mizo Warning: XSLTProcessor::importStylesheet() [function.XSLTProcessor-importStylesheet]: xsltParseStylesheetProcess : empty stylesheet in shopping/shop.php on line 8

Warning: XSLTProcessor::transformToXml() [function.XSLTProcessor-transformToXml]: No stylesheet associated to this object in shopping/shop.php on line 9

Comment: @sara, It looks like the opening `<xsl:stylesheet>` tag is somehow broken (it can't find the trailing `>`). Make sure the code stays intact when you paste it into your `shop.xsl`.

Comment: @sara, I added sample output to my answer. Which tags are missing?

Comment: @mizo i tried in IE , it now showing correctly.thanks for ur help

Comment: @sara, no problem. Remember to upvote the answers you found helpful. You should also select the most helpful answer as the accepted answer. That's the way we thank for help here in Stack Exchange :)

Comment: You could use `<xsl:for-each select="shops/shop[@incity='yes'][type='Botique']">` to save the two `xsl:if`'s. More readable IMO.

Answer (score 0):

**This is among the shortest possible transformations that is also one of the simplest and completely "in the spirit of XSLT**":

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="address">
  <address>
   <xsl:value-of select=
    "concat(streetno, ' ', streetname, ', ', suburb)"/>
  </address>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "@incity | shop[not(@incity='yes' and type='Botique')]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<shops>
    <shop incity="yes" onlineorder="yes">
        <type>Botique</type>
        <address>
            <streetno>23</streetno>
            <streetname>collins</streetname>
            <suburb>Melbourne</suburb>
        </address>
    </shop>
    <shop incity="yes" onlineorder="yes">
        <type>Botique</type>
        <address>
            <streetno>25</streetno>
            <streetname>little collins</streetname>
            <suburb>Melbourne</suburb>
        </address>
    </shop>
    <shop incity="no" onlineorder="yes">
        <type>Tailoring</type>
        <address>
            <streetno>2</streetno>
            <streetname>cosmos street</streetname>
            <suburb>Glenroy</suburb>
        </address>
    </shop>
</shops>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<shops>
   <shop onlineorder="yes">
      <type>Botique</type>
      <address>23 collins, Melbourne</address>
   </shop>
   <shop onlineorder="yes">
      <type>Botique</type>
      <address>25 little collins, Melbourne</address>
   </shop>
</shops>
```

**Do note**:

1. **Overriding of the "identity template"** -- the most fundamental and powerful XSLT design pattern.
2. **Pattern matching and absolutely no conditional XSLT instructions.**

Comment: Can you explaing why are you using `@incity | shop[not(@incity='yes' and type='Botique')]`? Is not `shop[not(@incity='yes' and type='Botique')]` enough?

Comment: @empo: The final output should not contain any `incity` attributes and this template is "deleting" them. This is something that even your updated solution has missed doing. :)

Comment: I see. Thanks. Anyway the humble solution I've proposed does not eliminate `incity` as it prevents selection of it.

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler XSL than anyone's IMO =p is the following, very readable, very simple:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <shops>
   <xsl:for-each select="shops/shop[@incity!='no']">
    <xsl:element name="shop">
     <xsl:attribute name="onlineorder"><xsl:value-of select="@onlineorder" /></xsl:attribute>
     <type><xsl:value-of select="type" /></type>
     <address>
      <xsl:value-of select="address/streetno" />
      <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="address/streetname" />
      <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="address/suburb" />
     </address>
    </xsl:element>
   </xsl:for-each>
  </shops>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It's simple, because it's basically HTML. Only attributes are different like this, so you need `xsl:element[name]` and `xsl:attribute[name]`.

**edit**
See XML, XSL and PHP source: http://hotblocks.nl/tests/xsl(t).php?source